# /MD in Visual Studio does not import from msvcr100.dll in Release configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a little bit strange problem, usually people tend to ask how to remove the reference to msvcrXX.dll from their executables, and I have an opposite problem: I need to force my executable to use msvcr100.dll. It is needed because I link an additional DLL that uses CRT to my project, and this DLL imports msvcr functions.

So I set the /MD option, and then when building in "Debug" I get a working code (msvcr100.dll is in the import table of the EXE), but when I try to compile "Release" I achieve a much bigger executable with the only imports from mylib.dll and kernel32.dll, which causes CRT to not being properly initialized and a runtime error because of this.

I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

in the code and, for example, 'printf' function is used.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Add:
The solution I've found: add "#define _DLL" in the beginning of the code and add msvcrt.lib to the additional dependencies. Google says, this is what "/MD" has to do, don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Why? If you use another DLL, and it imports msvcr100, then you're done. There's no reason to make your base executable imprt it, too.

Comment: For example, if he use `strtok()`( [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ). Anyway, did you set /MD on all configuration? ( /MDd on debug, /MD on release)

Comment: You forgot to change the setting for the Release configuration.

Comment: I've thought of writing that I've surely added /MD to the both configurations, but decided not to… Anyway, /MD is in the Release and in the Debug configurations. (Yes, not "/MDd" in the Debug, that'll cause problems).
bmargulies, it is the problem, that executable uses some other methods for (for example) console output that couldn't be used in the same time with the CRT. Actually, I don't know what is the exact purpose, but anyway, if main exe uses WriteFile for console instead of msvcr100.printf, and then the library tries fwrite(), it fails with a runtime error.

Comment: Maybe there is some other incompatible switch. Can you post compiler and linker command line? (for Release build)

Comment: That's it: http://pastie.org/4712059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found: add "#define _DLL" in the beginning of the code and add msvcrt.lib to the additional dependencies. Google says, this is what "/MD" has to do, don't know why it doesn't.

Any more beautiful ideas are still appreciated.